# Effect on expected value of conditioning on inequality between random variables (do we have E[X | X>S] ≥ E[X | X>S, Y>S]?)

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, random-variables, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I've been trying to prove the following inequality:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X \mid X > S] \geq \mathbb{E}[X  \mid  X>S, Y>S]
$$

where $X$, $Y$, $S$ are mutually independent real-valued random variables (let's make them absolutely continuous to simplify). The intuition why it might be true is simple enough: if you condition on $Y>S$, the posterior on $S$ is shifted “downwards”, and then the conditioning on $X>S$ is not as informative and raises the expected value of $X$ less.

To make it simple, I have not succeeded proving this and I'm starting to wonder if it's in fact true, so I would like to know if anybody has an idea.

For completeness, my most promising attempt used the correlation inequality. First we write:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X \mid X>S, Y>S] = \frac{1}{P(X>S, Y>S)}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p_S(s)P(Y>s)\int_s^{+\infty} p_X(x) x \,dx \,ds
$$

whence:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X \mid X>S, Y>S] = \frac{1}{P(X>S, Y>S)}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p_S(s)P(Y>s, X>s)\mathbb{E}[X \mid X>s] \,ds
$$

Take $f(s) = \mathbb{P}(X > s, Y > s)$ and $g(s) = \mathbb{E}[X  \mid  X > s]$. Because $f$ is decreasing and $g$ is increasing, we get:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X \mid X>S, Y>S] \leq \frac{1}{\dots} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} p_S(s) P(Y>s, X>s) \,ds\right) \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} p_S(s) \mathbb{E}[X \mid X>s] \,ds \right)
$$

i.e.:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X \mid X>S, Y>S] \leq \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{p_S(s)}{\mathbb{P}(X > s)} \int_s^{+\infty} p_X(x) x \,dx \,ds
$$

This is frustratingly close but not quite it; if you apply the correlation inequality again you get something that is too lax (by Jensen's inequality), and I'm worrying what I got here is too lax already, or that I made a mistake.

(Why do I care? It happens to be relevant to a Bayesian model of certain linguistic phenomena. Basically, if this is true, following a certain model, you predict that upon hearing “Alice and Bridget are tall”, people will not imagine Alice to be as tall as if they hear “Alice is tall”.)

Comment: I made it wrong.

Comment: It's a rearrangement inequality like what you argue in the 2rd paragraph, which equavlent to $\mathbb{E}[X\mid X>S]\mathbb{E}[1(Y>S)\mid X>S]\geq\mathbb{E}[X\,1(Y>S)\mid X>S]$. To use the rearrangement inequality, first integrate it by $X,S$ and then $Y$ and notice when $X$ increase, $X>S$ hold still for a fixed $S$ and $1(Y>S)$ will remain the same.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, posting it as an answer

Comment: Never mind, I think it still doesn't work? If I integrate in that order the best thing I get is this:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X|Y>S, X>S] \leq \frac{\mathbb{P}(X>S)}{\mathbb{P}(Y>S, X>S)} E[X | X > S] \int p_X(x) \mathbb{P}(Y>S|x>S)\,dx
$$
This isn't quite it, is it?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{E}[X|X>s]$ increase with $s$ increase and
$$\mathbb{E}[X|X>S]=\int_S\mathbb{E}[X|X>s]f_S(s)ds=\int_S(\int_{s}^{+\infty} x\,\frac{f_X(x)dx}{\mathbb{P}[X>S]})f_S(s)ds$$
The same for other terms and $E[1(Y>s)|X>s]=\int_{s}^{+\infty} (\int_s^{+\infty}1(y>s)\,f_Y(y)dy)\frac{f_X(x)ds}{\mathbb{P}[X>S]}$ decrease with s increase, so we can apply the rearrangement inequality.

Comment: The first equality you wrote is incorrect, I think. Instead it should be, if I got it right:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X | X > S] = \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(X>S)} \int_S \mathbb{E}[X|X>s] \mathbb{P}(X>s) f_S(s) \,ds
$$

Comment: Thinking about why this equality is wrong (it was also the problem for my initial attempt) makes me realize how to do it, posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so a small variation on my initial attempt works.

Let's rewrite it as:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X|X > S, Y > S] = \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(Y>S|X>S)} \int p_S(s) \frac{\mathbb{P}(X>s)}{\mathbb{P}(X>S)} \mathbb{P}(Y>s) \mathbb{E}[X|X>s]\,ds
$$

We apply the correlation inequality, crucially taking $p_S(s) \frac{\mathbb{P}(X>s)}{\mathbb{P}(X>S)}$ to be the density (this is the density of $S$ conditional on $X > S$). We get:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X|X > S, Y > S] \leq \frac{1}{\dots} \left(\int p_S(s) \frac{\mathbb{P}(X>s)}{\mathbb{P}(X>S)} \mathbb{P}(Y>s) \,ds\right) \left( \int p_S(s) \frac{\mathbb{P}(X>s)}{\mathbb{P}(X>S)} \mathbb{E}[X|X>s]\,ds \right)
$$

The first integral is $\mathbb{P}(Y>S|X>S)$. The second one is $\mathbb{E}[X|X>S]$. Yay!